# Workstation with two dedicated GPUs

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, dual-gpu

My workstation has two different Nvidia GPUs: a GTX1060 for gaming and a Quadro K6000 for working. I need to switch from one to the other and I was thinking about a solution which doesn't make me opening my WS and plugging and unplugging my GPUs: having installed both the graphics drivers, I was thinking about a three positions toggle switch: on one side for the GTX, on the middle no GPU selected and on the other side for the quadro, so that I can choose my GPU not on the hardware behaviour but on the "Electrical behaviour". Could this be a good idea? Are there any reason for which you wouldn't recommend this solution? Obvioulsy, I would change the switch position only when the WS is switched off.

Comment: What about having 2 profiles, where you have 1 of the 2 devices disabled via Device Manager in the profile? Switching profile then switches which GPU you have enabled.

Answer (score 1):

PCIe slot has 82 pins. You won't find a [82-pole 3-throw](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/285096/34837) switch, particularly not one that will work reliably at PCIe frequencies.

Physically swapping GPUs regularly is not a good idea too. Both the motherboard slot and contacts on GPUs are designed for a limited, relatively low number of insertions.

I'm not sure if you can have both drivers installed simultaneously, but try having the Quadro in the top slot and GTX in a second full-length slot at all times. You can disable and enable them separately in the Device Manager. Just make sure to enable the 2nd card first, plug the screen into it and then disable the 1st one.

It's also possible that just plugging the screen into another GPU will make it the primary one without disabling anything in the Device Manager. Give it a go.

If both drivers can't be installed simultaneously, you can have two separate instances of Windows installed, possibly with a shared user profile.

Keep in mind that some motherboards and CPUs will reduce top PCIe slot's bandwidth to 8 lanes when another device is inserted into the 2nd slot, reassigning remaining 8 lanes to that 2nd device. While this won't matter for the GTX (expected performance drop is about 1-3%), I'm not sure about the Quadro. That's why Quadro should be in the top slot. If you have a workstation-grade CPU and motherboard, it will likely always allocate full 16 lanes to 1st slot and 8 or maybe even 16 lanes to the other one.